# Ring of functions example

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone provide a simple concrete example for $S, R$ and $R^S$ from the definitions on the following [website](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ring_of_functions) so I can see what is really meant by a ring of functions.

Comment: It's a set of functions with the obvious ring structure. You know how to add functions over $\Bbb R$? This is the same thing but more abstractly put.

Comment: Can you provide an example $R$ and $R^S$ if $S$ is the set of natural numbers?

Comment: say $S=\Bbb N$ and $R = \Bbb R$ then $R^S$ is a set of sequences, e.g. $((-1)^n)_n$ is an element, which is the function $f(n)=(-1)^n$ for $n \in \Bbb N$. $((-1)^{n+1})_n$, i.e. $g(n)=(-1)^{n+1}$ is another, and $f+g =0$ as for all $n$ $f(n)+g(n)=0$ (if one is $1$ the other is $-1$ and vice versa). Etc.

Comment: Are there an infinite number of such functions?

Comment: Yes, of course, we can choose any value for an $n$, for all $n$... So these are infinite rings if $R$ (the range ring) is infinite and $S$ non-empty or the domain $S$ (which need not have any structure) is infinite and $|R| \ge 2$.

Comment: This yields a set of sequences only if $S$ are the natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, a sequence by definition is a function on $\Bbb N$. But it's only one of the many options for $S$, in general. We could look at reals-reals functions too, like $f(x)=x^2$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

The website you link gives the example of the ring of functions $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. The elements of this ring are precisely the real valued sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. The addition in this ring is inherited from the addition in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. 
$$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} + (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_n+ y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ~~.$$ 
The same is the case for multiplication i.e.

$$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cdot (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (x_n \cdot y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ~~.$$

Another example is the ring of functions of the form $\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ i.e. in your notation $\mathbb{R}^{\{1,2,3\}}$. Then addition is nothing else than the usual addition in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: In your last example where you have a finite set as a domain, can we still write that in general the addition is $f(x) + g(x) = (f + g)(x), x \in \{1,2,3\}$? The reason we utilize the vector addition analogy is because we know the number of elements that the function can take?

Comment: Regarding your first question: yes. In fact, let me give an example: Consider the function $f(1) = 0, f(2) = 0, f(3) = 1$ and $g(1) = 1, g(2) = 3, g(3) = 6$, then in vector notation we would write $f=(0, 0, 1)$ and $g = (1, 3, 6)$ and the sum of the two is $(f+g)(1) = 1, (f+g)(2) = 3, (f+g)(3) = 7$, or as vectors $f+g = (1,3,7)$. I am not sure what you mean by your second question.

Comment: You answered both, thank you.

Comment: Could you also please check out the following sentence from the same website: "When the natural numbers are defined in an axiomatic set-theoretical way, then n is often defined as { 0, 1, ..., n-1 }, namely, one defines 0 = {} and n+1 = { n } union n. With this definition, $R^S$ is actually identical to $R^n$." Do you maybe know what is meant by this? What kind of a set is the author building?